# SD card will not click into place

Tags: sdcard, panasonic-lumix, panasonic

I think this is a repair job, but thought I'd throw a question anyhow! 
I have a Panasonic lumix gx80 /85 which is just over a year old. I have not dropped or mistreated it, but now I find that the SD card no longer clicks into place.
 I've looked into the slot to check for any obstructions, but all appears OK. 
I've also tried using other SD cards. 
I can still use the camera as the door holds the SD card securely enough. However, this is not an ideal solution!

Comment: *"I think this is a repair job, but thought I'd throw a question anyhow! "* What, exactly, is your question here?

Comment: @MichaelClark  are there any suggestions to solving the problem, apart from taking the camera in for repairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some months later ...

I recently tried one of my older SD cards in the camera, and it clicked in!
 On closer inspection I've noticed that a tiny fragment of the SD card is broken!
 This presumably is jammed somewhere in the SD card slot and prevents any "unbroken" SD cards from clicking into place. 
 Now to practice some gynecological skills to see if I can locate and remove the broken piece. 
It would be helpful if i could actually see it!

Comment: "gynecological skills"? ... I suppose you can a plastic toothpick/flosser as a uterine sound to probe for the missing piece... But you should probably just get out more.